# MongoDb - Delete Json object from array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb

I would like to delete an object from a JSON objects array. Here is the schema

```
qualifications: {
    Experience: [{
      title: String,
      companyName: String,
      location: String,
      years: Number
    }],
    Education:[ {
      school: String,
      years: Number,
    }],
    Licences: [String],
    Honnors: [String],
  }
```

For example how can I delete the object whose key is "school": "harvard university" ?

What i tried is

```
const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.body.userid },
      {
        $pull: {
          qualifications: {
            Education: {
              school: "harvard university",
            }
          },
        },
      }
    );
```

But unfortunatelly it doesn't get deleted from the database. what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`qualifications` is an object, thus you can't use the `$pull` operator which requires an array field. Instead, you need the (`.`) dot notation to update the nested `Education` array: `qualifications.Education`.

```js
const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
{ _id: req.body.userid },
{
  $pull: {
    "qualifications.Education": {
      school: "harvard university"
    }
  }
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/F7vd_JRfnRM)

---

**Updated**

From your error message, it seems `qualifications` is an array instead of an object. Your schema should be as below:

```
qualifications: [{
    Experience: [{
      title: String,
      companyName: String,
      location: String,
      years: Number
    }],
    Education:[ {
      school: String,
      years: Number,
    }],
    Licences: [String],
    Honnors: [String],
  }]
```

To remove the object from the nested arrays, the below query aims to remove all the objects with `school: "harvard university"` from the `Education` array, for the all objects in the `qualifications` array,

```js
const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
{ 
  _id: req.body.userid,
  "qualifications.Education.school": "harvard university"
},
{
  $pull: {
    "qualifications.$[].Education": {
      school: "harvard university"
    }
  }
})
```

[Demo (remove object from nested arrays) @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tOl-RopG9fh)

Comment: I like that. but i get ```error": "Plan executor error during findAndModify :: caused by :: Cannot use the part (Education) of (qualifications.Education) to traverse the element ({qualifications: [ { Education: { school: \"harvard\", years: 2, _id: ObjectId('63ecd1f2e56205259fbae1db') } } ]})"``` To mention. I have a PUT request for this operation

Comment: From your error message, your `qualifications` is an array which is different with your schema. Can you confirm whether your schema is correct?

Comment: yes its correct. updated my code for the full schema

Comment: seems to work. although i have to change the POST method in the same way? because i got stuck

Answer (score 0):

can you try:

```
await User.update({ _id: req.body.userid },
          {
            "$pull": {
              "qualifications.Education": {
                  "school": "harvard university",
              },
            },
          });
```